# C++ Builder, TIdTCPServer's Multithread Handling

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++builder

I have a Server program which uses TIdTCPServer and a client side program.
I run my client program e.g 3 times on a single computer. Each time a client is connected, I try to add sometyhing to a Memo. Here is the problem. Since 3 clients are running at the sametime and  trying to connect to the server, when I run my server application. Both clients connect at the same time and since TIdTCPServer handle client connection on seperate threads, it causes deadlock(or something like that). I try to use a mutex

```
// Creation of mutex.Inside the constructor of TCPConnection class
ListViewMutex = CreateMutex( 
    NULL,                       // default security attributes
    FALSE,                      // initially not owned
    NULL);                      // unnamed mutex
```

//Somewhere else in my code

```
void __fastcall TCPConnection::OnConnect(TIdContext *AContext)
{
    DWORD dwWaitResult; 

    // Request ownership of mutex.

     dwWaitResult = WaitForSingleObject( 
        ListViewMutex,   // handle to mutex
        7000L);   // five-second time-out interval  
     Adapter->AddToMemo("OnConnect release");   
     ReleaseMutex(ListViewMutex);
     return; 
}
```

That is all. When I run my server and clients connect, my server application freezes. It even can't reach the line 'RelaseMutex(...)' 3 times (previously assumed 3 clients were connected)
When I remove Adapter->AddToMemo() line, It can reach the ReleaseMutex(...) line 3 times (but of course that code does nothing)

Am I using mutex in wrong way, or what is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

`TIdTCPServer` is multithreaded.  Its `OnConnect`, `OnDisconnect`, and `OnExecute` events run in the context of a worker thread.  It is not safe to access VCL UI controls from outside of the main UI thread.  Using a mutex is not adequate protection.  UI code MUST be run in the main thread.

Indy has `TIdSync` and `TIdNotify` classes to delegate code to the main thread, similar to the `TThread::Synchronize()` and `TThread::Queue()` methods.  Try something like this:

```
#include <IdSync.hpp>

class AddToMemoNotify : class TIdNotify
{
protected:
    TMyAdapterClass *m_Adapter;   
    String m_Msg;

    virtual void __fastcall DoNotify()
    {
        m_Adapter->AddToMemo(m_Msg);   
    }

public:
    __fastcall AddToMemoNotify(TMyAdapterClass *Adapter, const String &Msg) :
        TIdNotify(), m_Adapter(Adapter), m_Msg(Msg)
    {
    }
};
```

```
void __fastcall TCPConnection::OnConnect(TIdContext *AContext)
{
    (new AddToMemoNotify(Adapter, "Client Connected")->Notify();
}

void __fastcall TCPConnection::OnDisconnect(TIdContext *AContext)
{
    (new AddToMemoNotify(Adapter, "Client Disconnected")->Notify();
}
```

`TIdNotify` is a self-freeing object, it will destroy itself after `DoNotify()` has exited. So do not `delete` it manually.

Answer (score 0):

VCL GUI access is not thread safe.  Use TTHread::Synchronize or TThread::Queue to access the main thread.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I'm unable to get access to Synchronize or Queue methods because the execute or onConnect methods of TIdTCPServer (TIdTCPServer itself) arenot derived from TThread class. I think in order to use Synchronize or Queue methods can be used if they are used in a class derived from TThread

Comment: I was using my TCPServer class Derived from TObject. Now I changed TObject to TThread and derived my TCPServer from it, I can use Synchronize() method. But still don't know if it will work accurately. Thanks

Comment: I believe that there are static versions of TThread::Queue and TThread::Synchronize that do not require your class to be derived from TThread.

Comment: Indy has its own `TIdSync` and `TIdNotify` classes that are wrappers around `TThread::Synchronize()` and `TThread::Queue()`.